# Equivalent of C++ STL container "pair<T1, T2>" in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, stl, std-pair

I'm new to Objective-C, so please don't judge me too much. I was wondering: Is there an equivalent of the C++ STL pair container I can use in Objective-C?

I want to build an array that contains an NSInteger associated to an NSBool. I know I could use an array with each entry being a NSDictionary with a single key-value but I find it to be a little overkill.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: While there is no natural replacement in Objective-C (or actually - Cocoa Foundation framework) for a "Pair", several answers below provide acceptable solutions that can be used. I also added a somewhat-forced solution, that will behave in a similar way - but choosing the right solution will largely depend on the actual use you have to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the STL in Objective-C++. All you need to do is change the extension of your .m file to .mm and I would also advise you use `#import` instead of `#include`. That way you can use your pair STL container.

Comment: Just keep in mind that STL containers do not `retain` and `release` objects.

Answer (score 16):

You can write your own data structure object - for such a simple case, it would be pretty easy:

```
@interface Pair : NSObject 
{
    NSInteger integer;
    BOOL      boolean;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) integer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) boolean;
@end
```

And a matching implementation, then you stick your `Pair` objects into the `NSArray` problem free.

Comment: @Martin, absolutely true.  But the OP seems to indicate that he wants a specific pair.  Replacing the two properties here with `id` would get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Using anonymous struct and struct literals, you might be able to do something like

```
NSValue * v = [NSValue valueWithBytes:(struct {NSInteger i; bool b;}){i,b} objCType:(struct {NSInteger i; bool b;})];
```

and then to read,

```
struct {NSInteger i; bool b;} foo;
[v getValue:&foo];
```

It's a bit cleaner if you name your struct though.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Pair category on NSNumber that uses associated objects, something like the code below (untested, may require iOS4 as I'm not sure when associated objects were introduced).

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSNumber(Pair)

#define PAIR_KEY 'p'

- (NSNumber *) pairNumber:(NSNumber *)second
{
    char secondKey = PAIR_KEY;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &secondKey, second, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    return self;
}

- (NSNumber *) pairedNumber
{
    char secondKey = PAIR_KEY;
    NSNumber *associatedObject = (NSNumber *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &secondKey);    
    return associatedObject;
}

@end
```

You would use it like so:

```
BOOL myBool = NO;

NSNumber *storedBool = [NSNumber numberWithBool:myBool];

[myOtherNumber pairNumber:storedBool];
```

And to get it out:

```
NSNumber *boolNumber = [myOtherNumber pairedNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, is to (ab)use a single-entry NSDictionary for storing the pair - since NSDictionary can now be defined to force typed "key" and "value" and also supports literals as syntactic sugar. The drawback - the pair can only hold NSObjects (instance references) and not primitive values.

A sample would look like this:

```
typedef NSDictionary<NSString *, NSDate *> *Pair;
```

And then in your code:

```
Pair myPair = @{@"my name": [NSDate date]};
Pair myOtherPair =  @{@"his name": [NSDate date]};
NSArray<Pair> *myArrayOfPairs = @[myPair, myOtherPair];
```

Go on and print the results:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArrayOfPairs);
```

and it looks very much like what you'd expect.

```
2019-03-18 16:08:21.740667+0200 TesterApp[23135:23269890] (
  {
    "my name" = "2019-03-18 14:08:21 +0000";
  },
  {
    "his name" = "2019-03-18 14:08:21 +0000";
  }
)
```

Payback time comes as you try to extract values from the so-called "Pair". You have to actually dig that single entry from the NSDictionary, not by its "Key" as usual,  but assuming there's only one entry, like this:

```
Pair somePair = myArrayOfPairs.lastObject;
NSString *name = somePair.allKeys.firstObject;
NSDate *date = somePair.allValues.firstObject;
NSLog(@"name: %@ date: %@", name, date);
```

which finally yields:

```
name: his name date: Mon Mar 18 16:16:43 2019
```

I don't especially recommend this alternative, but it has its niceties and benefits.