# A class like CGPoint, but with integers (to represent position in a grid)

Tags: ios, objective-c, grid

Is there a built-in class in iOS, which could be used to represent a position in a grid?

I.e. something like `CGPoint`, but with integer members instead of floats.

I've searched in [CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) and other docs, but couldn't find such a class yet (it is difficult to search with such keywords).

I know I can create my custom class myself, but I'm hoping for a useful "builtin" class with nice methods.

I need it for [a word game](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/GameBoard.m) to represent tile positions:

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of C++ STL container "pair<T1, T2>" in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524221/equivalent-of-c-stl-container-pairt1-t2-in-objective-c)

Comment: CGPoint is not a *class* but a ( plain old ) C-struct.

Comment: You can create your own struct with integers.

Comment: That's what I've written in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin R points out CGPoint is a [struct](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm), not a class. That being said, there is no built in method for this. You could use CGPoint an just cast accordingly throughout your code, or you can define your own struct like this:

```
struct CGIntegerPoint {
    NSInteger xPos;
    NSInteger yPos;
};

typedef struct CGIntegerPoint CGIntegerPoint;

CG_INLINE CGIntegerPoint CGIntegerPointMake(NSInteger x, NSInteger y) {
    CGIntegerPoint point;
    point.xPos = x;
    point.yPos = y;
    return point;
}
```

This now gives you a new declared type CGIntegerPoint, and a corresponding static inline function CGIntegerPointMake() which takes two arguments (x,y) and returns a CGIntegerPoint.

**Note:** In the future, you may find it helpful to command-click on types in Xcode. Doing so will jump you to the type's definition, which in this case, is also it's implementation.

Comment: Using CGPoint would have the side effect that you cannot use its components as array indices (which is probably required here) because they are not integers. (Btw, congratulations to your moderator election!)

Comment: @MartinR I should rephrase that. I only meant side effects that couldn't be easily overcome.